# how to release an event as fast as possible, in F#

Tags: f#, event-handling

I have a situation where I am receiving events by burst, from a socket connection. There can be suddenly a lot of events and then nothing for a little while (as in 100ms maybe, so not that long).

When the data arrives, it comes from a RabbitMQ callback and I need to return from that callback as soon as possible.
I used to process the data in the callback and this has caused buffering problems, which turned into connection problems.

So, I'd like to put the data that arrives in a queue and return from the event as fast as possible, then let another thread get the data, but through an event as well.

As this is a mechanism that needs to be used in several places, I made a Type for it but this code hasn't been tested yet in the main system. It'll take a bit of work to integrate and I would like first to get these questions addressed:

- Is there any existing mechanism in .NET that would already achieve this.
- Is this code making sense (in a way this may be more asking about a code review than a pure question, but the question above warrants posting here instead of the code review site)

The code and its test is here:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Concurrent
open System.Threading


type EventThreadDecoupling<'a>() =

    // data queue
    let queue = ConcurrentQueue<'a>()

    // event called when an element is in the queue
    let popEvent = Event<'a>()

    // wait handle, triggered when data gets put in the queue
    let eventHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset)

    // setup the thread that processes the queue
    do
        async {
            while true do
                // there is a 1s timeout just in case there is data
                // that was added while I reset the eventHandle
                eventHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.)) |> ignore
                let mutable dataRead = false
                while not queue.IsEmpty do
                    match queue.TryDequeue() with
                    | true, v -> popEvent.Trigger(v)
                                 dataRead <- true
                    | _, _    -> ()

                if dataRead then
                    eventHandle.Reset() |> ignore
        } |> Async.Start

    // event called when data has arrived
    member this.OnEvent =
        popEvent.Publish

    // push data to the queue
    member this.Push(data: 'a) =
        queue.Enqueue(data)
        eventHandle.Set() |> ignore


[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =

    let r = Random()

    let e = EventThreadDecoupling<DateTime>()

    e.OnEvent.Add(fun d ->
        printfn "%A: received %A" DateTime.Now d
    )

    while true do
        Thread.Sleep(r.Next(200))
        e. Push(DateTime.Now)

    0
```

Comment: Microsoft's Reactive Framework aka System.Reactive or Observables. They're built-in to F#. It would handle this perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to create an agent which makes use of F# **MailboxProcessor**. In your RabbitMQ callback you don't do anything except forwarding (posting) the received message (data) to the agent. The MailboxProcessor will do the queueing for you so you don't need to reinvent the wheel here.

The code would be:

```
type Agent<'Msg> (processMsg) =
    let inbox = MailboxProcessor<'Msg>.Start <| fun inbox ->
        let rec loop () = async {
            let! msg = inbox.Receive ()
            processMsg msg
            return! loop ()
        }
        loop ()
    member this.Post msg =
        inbox.Post msg

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =    
    let evt = Event<_> ()
    let agent = Agent<DateTime> (fun msg ->
        printfn "Processing msg: %A" msg
        Thread.Sleep 3000
        printfn "Processed msg: %A" msg
    )

    evt.Publish.Subscribe (fun msg ->
        printfn "Received: %A" msg
        // forward msg to the agent:
        agent.Post msg)
    |> ignore

    let rec loop () = async {
        do! Async.Sleep 500
        evt.Trigger DateTime.Now
        return! loop ()
    }
    let cts = new CancellationTokenSource ()
    Async.Start (loop (), cts.Token)
    Console.ReadKey true |> ignore
    cts.Cancel ()

    0
```

If you run this code you will see the text `"Received: xxx"` is regularly printed every 500ms no matter how long you process the message received in the agent.

Answer (score -1):

F# has `MailboxProcessor`. It sounds like this would be a good fit for this problem.

https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-actor-model/

Comment: Please don't post "link-only" answers. Please put the salient details in the answer itself and only link to provide supporting evidence.